# Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Tags: vb.net

```
 Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As    
   System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    If R2.Checked Then
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [maint] where   
 [centrale]='" & centralev.Text & "' ", MyConn) 'Change items to your 
  database name
    End If
    If R1.Checked Then
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [maint] where 
 datevisite='" & dateintervention.Value.ToShortDateString() & "'  ", 
 MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
    End If
    da.Fill(ds, "maint") 'Change items to your database name
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DGV.DataSource = view

End Sub
End Class
```

I used 2 buttonradio to select criteria of search , I have problem with date search, Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Comment: What does `dateintervention.Value` return?

Comment: apparently, the column type is Date but you are passing text/string in the query.  Use Parameters and this is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

try to change

incorrect

```
 da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [maint] where 
 datevisite='" & dateintervention.Value.ToShortDateString() & "'  ", 
 MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
```

correct

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [maint] where 
 datevisite='" & dateintervention.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "'  ", 
 MyConn) 'Change items to your database name
```

[Example for format](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Plutonix comment to your question you can try:

```
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select * from [maint] where datevisite = ?")

Dim param = New OleDbParameter("@datevisite", OleDbType.Date)
param.Value = dateintervention.Value

cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

da = New OleDbDataAdapter (cmd, MyConn)
```

In this way ADO.NET will take care for you to replace the question mark in the query text with the proper date value formatted as required by OleDb syntax. You entirely avoid string concatenation errors and you don't need to learn any formatting rule for all available OleDb data types.

Besides it should be safer.